# Trusty TEE implementation

Tags: java, android, security, android-studio

I am currently working on banking app in Android(native development with Java, JNI but not in PhoneGap, ionic etc.). I have search a lot but did not find any tutorial for the same.

> [trustonic](https://www.trustonic.com/news/blog/writing-first-application-using-tee/): very very expensive
>
> for [Trusty TEE](https://source.android.com/security/trusty/) but not understood how to use it and where to use?

Question:

1. How to communicate with trusted application?
2. How to install trusted application to trustzone OS with client application?
3. what will it need to implement(like libtee)?
4. is there any example available? if yes please provide the same.
5. How [Trusty APIs](https://source.android.com/security/trusty/trusty-ref) call and if we need to do modify in code how to do that?

Answer (score 3):

earlier I had worked on TEE development. But, never I used to use any SDK or plugin for the development. It was all AOSP. So, as you pointed out it is hard to find write-up openly available. There are set of sample sources available, which you may want to try along with your stock source. Here is the [link](https://android.googlesource.com/trusty/app/sample/).
You can also use build system applications (along with your system builds) using the API's from [google](https://source.android.com/security/trusty/#downloading_building). Then, you can just pull the application from system image and publish it (I know it's not a good idea!).If I can publish any blogs, I think it may help.